# PN junction capacitance and varactor diodes

Tags: diodes, capacitance

I do know that a PN junction when expanded for a diode when in reverse biase will cause that diode to act like a capacitor, but what sets the varactor diode apart from other diodes?

Comment: It's just tailored to give a bigger change in capacitance for a change in control voltage. If you are asking what happens at the atomic level that is different to normal diodes I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

All junction diodes will 'varact', but some are optimised for use in tuning circuits, and called 'varactors'<sup>1</sup>. In a general purpose diode, the varactance is a side effect, and is not well controlled.

The diode in a tuning circuit needs to be low intrinsic resistance, for high tuned circuit Q.

One measure of how 'good' a varactor is, is the tuning ratio between the lowest and highest voltage. This can be achieved by several things.

- minimising the size of the electrodes, so a higher percentage of the junction is actually varacting
- having a high breakdown voltage, to push the low capacitance end
- having low loss and a well-controlled doping profile so that the low voltage high capacitance end is usable, and more importantly, predictable from component to component

Some varactors are specified to have a particular voltage/capacitance tuning law, this requires a particular doping profile.

<sup>1</sup>Just as all minority carrier diodes will 'snap off', but only some are sold as step recovery diodes (STRDs). I worked with a very good engineer who would never use a £1 component when a 1p one would do. The design called for a STRD to use in a multiplier from 500 MHz to 2.5 GHz. A genuine one would have been several pounds. A BA482 silicon switching diode was a few pence, and worked sufficiently well.

Answer (score 1):

A varactor diode is specifically designed to exploit the capacitance characteristics that you observe in a typical PN junction when it's reverse-biased. While many diodes can exhibit a change in capacitance with varying reverse bias, varactors (or varicaps) are optimized for this purpose.

> what sets the varactor diode apart from other diodes?

Here's what sets a varactor diode apart from other diodes:

The primary purpose of a varactor diode is to function as a voltage-controlled capacitor. It's commonly used in frequency-tuning applications, like in VCOs (Voltage-Controlled Oscillators) and RF circuits. Traditional diodes are not optimized for this application. Varactor diodes are designed to have a wider and more predictable range of capacitance change as a function of the applied reverse voltage.
Varactors are designed to have a high-quality factor (Q). A high-Q means that the varactor will introduce less loss in RF circuits. The doping profile of the varactor diode's PN junction is specifically tailored to maximize the capacitance variation with voltage and to have predictable capacitance characteristics. Varactor diodes might be packaged in ways to minimize parasitic inductance and capacitance, ensuring that they perform effectively at high frequencies. For a varactor diode, manufacturers will often provide models or equations that describe how the capacitance varies with voltage. This is critical for design purposes. For typical diodes, this characteristic is not always well-defined or characterized.
The capacitance of a varactor diode is nonlinear with respect to the applied voltage, which is an important feature for certain applications. This nonlinear capacitance can be exploited in mixer circuits or for frequency multiplication.

Unlike regular diodes which are often optimized for high forward currents, varactor diodes are not typically used in forward-biased mode and thus are not optimized for forward conduction.

In summary, while the principle of capacitance change with reverse voltage exists in all diodes, varactor diodes are optimized in design, doping, and packaging to function effectively as voltage-controlled capacitors.